# Two GPUs on one pc configuration?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I've heard that it is possible to have two seperate graphics cards on the same machine and switch between them using software. The idea is that you could have one for gaming and a professional grade for heavy duty editing and stuff like that (i must clarify that i am not talking about cards in SLI or crossfire). Is it possible? If so how? Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you asking about? Are you talking about laptops (with one output hardwired to one GPU) or desktops (with each GPU having its own output)?

Comment: @grawity No, I am talking about a single desktop pc with two dedicated graphics cards which are connected to the same monitor. Also i'm working with windows.